# Page stops rendering

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a JSP page that surprisingly stops rendering when it deployed to a server. But when I place JavaScript `alert()` at different positions on that page the page start rendering as it should. Eventually, when I remove those alerts the page keeps on rendering. When I run that page on my eclipse as localhost it runs fine and I don't need to include JavaScript `alerts()`.I pretty much hope that you fully understood my question.

Comment: I get your question, but because I can't see the actual code it'll be impossible to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

without seeing you code its almost impossible to tell whats the problem - but there's one thing i can think of:

yiu're doing some ajax-stuf without understanding what asynchonus requests are - by insering an alert() somewhere, the code is stoped and the ajax-request is completed in the time you need to klick 'ok'. if so:

- please try to set your ajax-requests to behave 'synchonous' (thets a bad idea in most cases, but maybe helps to find the problem)

if that works:

- reset it to behave asynchronous and search for the failure

if not / you aren't using ajax:

- post the relevant code-parts

generally:

- try to use something like firebug and look for javascript-failures